# How to find out how much disk space does a Set take up in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

The closest that I found is using the `info` command of the `asmonitor` tool but it only goes as granular as the disk usage of the Namespace. Possibly using the Aerospike Java client would be cool, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of records in a set using asinfo:

`asinfo -v sets -l`

You would then need to know the avg record size in your set.

Otherwise, you would have to write a UDF and do a scan aggregation (but as far as I understand, this would still be a rough approximation as there is no easy way to know exactly how much is used internally through a UDF reading the bins of a record).